# Output Needed in Java

Tags: java

3! = 3*2*1 = 6

WITHOUT USING LOOP

Thank you!

My function below :

```
    public static int factorial(int n)
    {    
         if ((n == 1) || (n == 0))  

           return 1; 

         else    

           return(n * factorial(n-1));
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Your recursive factorial method looks correct.  However, in a strange turn of events you decided to obtain user input from the `FF` constructor.  This is unusual and should not be done.

Comment: No idea what you are asking for - you currently don't have a loop, you have recursion.

Comment: You are already using recursion to find factorial of a number and which is not iterative itself. Can you please explain your problem little more in details

Answer (score 1):

You can print the value of the parameter passed in the factorial method like this:

create a function:

```
    public static int factorial(int n) {
        System.out.print(n);   // here
        if (n > 1) System.out.print("*");  // and here
        if ((n == 1) || (n == 0))
            return 1;
        else {
            return (n * factorial(n - 1));
        }
    }
```

Produces:

```
3!=3*2*1=6
```

Comment: While this may solve the OP's immediate question, it seems to me bad practice to put user input code into the constructor, because the code is non reusale and can only be called once.  To see why, imagine that an exception happens in the constructor, then the JVM would finish initializing the object, but now the factorial would not have been created properly.  And we can't call the constructor a second time.

Comment: @OP you should listen to Tim here. Thanks for the comment, Tim.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global variable (StringBuffer) and append the numbers to it from the factorial method. Use this variable from main method when you print.